# What these SVN command lines do in detail?

Tags: svn, command-line

`svn co svn://svn.fazend.com/abc/branches/pqr-staging pqr`

`cd pqr`

`svn merge ^/trunk/xyz.com`

`do some changes in here and`

`svn ci -m " some comment about your change"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to read the svnbook mentionied by schlenk.

```
svn co svn://svn.fazend.com/abc/branches/pqr-staging pqr
```

Check out from the mentioned repository and put the files in (a new) pqr directory. The new directory is your working copy.

```
cd pqr
```

Change to the pqr directory.

```
svn merge ^/trunk/xyz.com
```

Merge the changes from a different working copy (^/trunk/xyz.com) into your working copy (pqr). The only reasonable explanation for the ^ I can find is "parent directory" on RISC OS.

```
do some changes in here and
```

Make additional changes in the working copy, usually needed to resolve any conflicts.

```
svn ci -m " some comment about your change"
```

Commit the merge result and your changes to the repository.

Comment: thanks a lot mate, that helped, i ve been using SVN but not command line neither branching and merging, so was a bit confused, really appreciate.
This was what i was precisely looking for.

Comment: I'm curious about the ^. Are you running RISC OS? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: the caret sign (^) didnt not work for me in windows so i replaced the caret sign by "svn://svn.fazend.com/abc" and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the nice documentation in the freely available SVN book:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/index.en.html

Comment: I know that book, but I wanted quick answers, so guys please can you help me with quick explanation of the same.
I would really appreciate.